# Error: 'Msn.VE.API.Globals.vemapinstances' is null or not an object

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering why I'm getting a runtime error: "Error: 'Msn.VE.API.Globals.vemapinstances' is null or not an object" when running the javascript on my page below. The html for the page is below. I'm trying to have jquery dialog pop up that has a control and a cancel button for the user to interact with. "divFollow" class contains one type of control that the user will interact with, and "divFriend" class contains another control for the user to interact with. Below, these controls for the user to interact with are within a table. Any help? Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.FriendControl').click(showDialogFriend);
    $('.FollowControl').click(showDialogFollow);
    $('#ButtonFriendClose').click(closeDialogFriend);
    $('#ButtonFollowClose').click(closeDialogFollow);

    $('.divFollow').dialog({ height: 350,
        width: 550,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        position: 'center',
        autoOpen: false,
        overlay: { opacity: 0.5, background: 'black' }
    });
    $('.divFriend').dialog({ height: 350,
        width: 600,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        position: 'center',
        autoOpen: false,
        overlay: { opacity: 0.5, background: 'black' }
    });
}
)

//function to show dialog Friend and Follow   
var showDialogFriend = function () {
    //if the contents have been hidden with css, you need this
    $('.divFriend').show();
    //open the dialog
    $('.divFriend').dialog("open");
}
var showDialogFollow = function () {
    //if the contents have been hidden with css, you need this
    $('.divFollow').show();
    //open the dialog
    $('.divFollow').dialog("open");
}

//function to close dialog Friend and Follow, called by a button in the dialog
var closeDialogFriend = function () {
    $('.divFriend').dialog("close");
}

var closeDialogFollow = function () {
    $('.divFollow').dialog("close");
}
```

And here's a snippet from my html:

```
<div class="divFollow"> 
        <asp:Table ID="TableFollow" runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Right"> 
                    <input id="ButtonFollowClose" name="ButtonFollowClose" value="Close" type="button" />
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <CMS:Invite ID="InviteControl" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" /> 
                </asp:TableCell>                   
            </asp:TableRow>               
        </asp:Table>                 
    </div>

    <div class="divFriend"> 
        <asp:Table ID="TableFriend" runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Right"> 
                    <input id="ButtonFriendClose" name="buttonFriend" value="Close" type="button" />
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <CMS:CommunitySearch ID="CommunitySearchID" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
                </asp:TableCell>                   
            </asp:TableRow>               
        </asp:Table>                 
    </div>

<div class="blogPost clearfix">
  <a class="FriendControl" href="#" >Friend</a>
  <a class="FollowControl" href="#" >Follow</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this in all browsers, or just IE? Any particular version?

Comment: The error does not appear to be with your javascript code. The `Msn.VE.API.Globals.vemapinstances` indicates the problem is in the Bing Maps code, or due to some way that your code is breaking the Bing Maps code. Can you try removing your code first and seeing if you still get the error?

Comment: I do not get an error when I comment out my javascript above. Thanks for your help so far! What do you suggest now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try fixing up some of the little mistakes in your Javascript highlighted by JSLint. For example, whenever you have:

```
var something = function() {
     // ...
}
```

Make sure you put a trailing semicolon, since you are ending a variable declaration statement after all. i.e.

```
var something = function() {
     // ...
};
```

Also, change the last two lines of the `$(document).ready()` code to have the `}` and the `)` on the same line, followed by a semicolon. Javascript can do some weird things with trying to insert semicolons for you automatically, which can lead to broken code.

i.e. it should be in the format:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // ...
});
```

Give those a try and see how you go. Also, let us know what browser this is happening in - have you tested in other browsers?

Comment: I made those changes you mentioned, but still get the same runtime error: "msn.VE.API.Globals.vemapinstances' is null or not an object

Comment: I'm using Internet Explorer8. Problem seems to be with any browser. Should I use IE developer tools and check to see if anything is null? I'm not really sure how to do this properly. When I "step into" code, I'm mostly in minified jquery.

Comment: It's difficult to explain without playing with it myself, but one thing you could do to help track it down is to swap the jQuery to use the non-minified version so you can read the code and maybe get clues why it is referring to `msn.VE.API.Globals.vemapinstances` at all. You may find the call stack and Javascript debugging inside Firebug to be better tools for the job than IE's more limited developer tools.

Hard to give you much more of a concrete answer, I'm afraid.